# How to copy a PostgreSQL RDS database within an RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I had so much trouble doing this - I thought I would make a Q/A on StackOverflow to explain the process.

The question is about copying an RDS postgres database for development usage - especially for testing database migrations scripts, etc.  That's why the focus on a "single schema" within a "single database".

In my case, I want to create a test database that's as isolated as possible, while remaining within a single RDS instance (because spinning up entire RDS instances takes anywhere from 5 - 15 minutes and because I'm cheap).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an answer using only the command line.

Pre-requisites:

- you must have Postgres client tools installed (don't need the actual server)

  - client version must be same or higher than your postgres server version
- network access to the RDS instance
- credentials for accessing the relevant database accounts

Example context:

- I have an RDS instance at `rds.example.com` which has a master user named [`rds_master`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html).
- I have an "application user" named `db_dev_user`, a database named `dev_db` that contains the schema `app_schema`.
- note that "user" and "role" in postgres are synonymous

Note: this guide was written in 2017, for postgres version 9.6.
If you find that some steps are no longer working on a recent version of postgres - please do post any fixes to this post as comments or alternative answers.

---

**pg_dump** prints out the schema and data of the original database and *will* work even while there are active connections to the database. Of course, performance for those connections is likely to be affected, but the resultant copy of the DB  **is** [transactional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13751/65893).

```
pg_dump --host=rds.example.com --port=5432 \
  --format=custom \
  --username=db_dev_user --dbname=dev_db \
  > pgdumped
```

---

The **createuser** command creates the user that your test application/processes should connect with (for better isolation), note that the created user is not a superuser and it cannot create databases or roles.

```
createuser --host=rds.example.com --port=5432 \
  --username=rds_master \
  --no-createdb --no-createrole --no-superuser \
  --login --pwprompt \
  db_test_user
```

---

Without this next **grant** command the following `createdb` will fail:

```
psql --host=rds.example.com --port=5432 \
  --username=rds_master --dbname=postgres \
  --command="grant db_test_user TO rds_master"
```

---

**createdb** does what it says on the tin; note that the `db_test_user` role "owns" the DB.

```
createdb --host=rds.example.com --port=5432 \
  --username=rds_master --owner=db_test_user test_db
```

---

The **create schema** command is next.  The `db_test_user` cannot create the schema, but it must be authorized for the schema or the `pg_restore` would fail because it would end up trying to restore into the `pg_catalog` schema (so note that `user=rds_master`, but `dbname=test_db`).

```
psql --host=rds.example.com --port=5432 \
  --username=rds_master --dbname=test_db \
  --command="create schema app_schema authorization db_test_user"
```

---

Finally, we issue the **pg_restore** command, to actually create the schema objects (tables, etc.) and load the data into them:

```
pg_restore --host=rds.example.com --port=5432 \
  --verbose --exit-on-error --single-transaction \
  --username=db_test_user --schema=app_schema \
  --dbname=test_db --no-owner \
  ./pgdumped
```

- `exit-on-error` - because otherwise finding out what went wrong involves too much scrolling and scanning (also it's implied by `single-transaction` anyway)
- `single-transaction` - avoids having to drop or recreate the DB if things go pear-shaped
- `schema` - only do the schema we care about (can also supply this to the original `pg_dump` command)
- `dbname` - to ensure use of the DB we created
- `no-owner`  - we're connecting as `db_test_user` anyway, so everything should be owned by the right user

Comment: `pg_dump` works, but dumping direct from RDS seems to be excruciatingly slow. We're talking ~500KB/s->2MB/s for tables that are 50GB is size on gigabit connections. I can only imagine there is some throttling or limitation RDS-side?

Answer (score 6):

For production, you'd be better off just taking an RDS snapshot of your instance and restoring that, which will create an entirely new RDS instance.

On a mostly empty database - it takes a few minutes to create the snapshot and another 5 minutes or so to create the new RDS instance (that's part of why it's a pain during development).

You will be charged for the new RDS instance only while it is running.  Staying within the free tier is one of the reasons I wanted to create this DB with the same instance for development purposes, plus not having to deal with a second DNS name; and that effect is multiplied as you start to have multiple small development environments.

Running a second RDS instance is the better option for production because you nearly completely eliminate any risk to your original DB.  Also, when you're dealing with real amounts of data - snapshot/DB creation times will be dwarfed by the amount of time spent reading/writing the data.  For large amounts of data, it's likely the Amazon RDS snapshot creation/restore process is going to have far better parallelisation than a set of scripts running on a single server somewhere.  Additionally, the RDS console gives you visilibility into the progress of the restore - which becomes invaluable as the dataset grows larger and more people become involved.